# Cant access object value from within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```js
{"-L0bFExUeZXB3-MUXCda":{"Comment":"GOOD","Date":"18 December","User":"OlaNord"}}

{"-L0bFCJh5SPUOWMjTRKu":{"Comment":"ok","Date":"18 December","User":"OlaNord"}}

{"-L0bFA2uzsGDizxxzN1p":{"Comment":"wewwe","Date":"18 December","User":"OlaNord"}}
```

I have an array of some `objects` inside. I need to access different `values`.When I try to retrieve the `key` name, I get `undefined`.

Here's my code:

```js
// Path for selected category
var categoryRef = firebase.database().ref("forum/" + currentCategory);

categoryRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        var key = user.uid;
        var postComments = [];

        for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
            var comments = snapshot.val()[key]['comments'];
            postComments.push(comments);
        }
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the json that comes in the snapshot, not the picture of it, it is hard to understand

Comment: What is being logged? Snapshot?

Comment: the picture is the array after the value is pushed.

Comment: @SanderHellesø can you just stringify and post the array rather? `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));`

Comment: added the json now

Comment: var comments = snapshot.val()[key]['Comment']; make changes in key name

Comment: 'comments' is the database ref name. 'Comment' is the actual user data

Comment: So user "Comment" that you got in actual user data.try my answer bellow

Comment: are you trying to push all the comments in an array like: `postComments = [
  "GOOD",
  "ok",
  "wewwe"
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try accessing the Comment as below, if the array you have posted in question can be iterated as below:

```js
var data = [{
        "-L0bFExUeZXB3-MUXCda": {
            "Comment": "GOOD",
            "Date": "18 December",
            "User": "OlaNord"
        }
    },

    {
        "-L0bFCJh5SPUOWMjTRKu": {
            "Comment": "ok",
            "Date": "18 December",
            "User": "OlaNord"
        }
    },

    {
        "-L0bFA2uzsGDizxxzN1p": {
            "Comment": "wewwe",
            "Date": "18 December",
            "User": "OlaNord"
        }
    }
]

var postComments = [];
for (var key of data) {
    for (var values in key) {
        console.log(key[values].Comment) //access the comment
        postComments.push(key[values].Comment);
    }
}

console.log(postComments);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Path for selected category
var categoryRef = firebase.database().ref("forum/" + currentCategory);

categoryRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        var key = user.uid;
        var postComments = [];

        for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
            var comments = snapshot.val()[key]['Comment'];
             //CHange key Name
            postComments.push(comments);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to access the values inside a key.

```js
var data = [{"-L0bFExUeZXB3-MUXCda":{"Comment":"GOOD","Date":"18 December","User":"OlaNord"}},{"-L0bFCJh5SPUOWMjTRKu":{"Comment":"ok","Date":"18 December","User":"OlaNord"}},{"-L0bFA2uzsGDizxxzN1p":{"Comment":"wewwe","Date":"18 December","User":"OlaNord"}}];
var result = data.reduce((r,o) => r.concat(Object.values(o).map(({Comment}) => Comment)),[]);
console.log(result);
```